# How to set up new GN hair with Solidify?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So I have some troubles with new geometry nodes hair system and solidify modifier. To make this properly animated I have to set up hair generation on base model and then move hair using Surface deform. It doesn't work when base mesh have solidify modifier.

[image]

So I suppose that this is caused by overlapping in UV's. So I recreated solidify modifier with Geometry nodes, and shift UV so that it should not overlap.

[image]

It makes some hair curves to follow the mesh, around 5% but most of them still fails. Am I missed something or does an outer better way exist?

- I do not want to apply solidify modifier
- I do not want to use old hair system because I want to have everything unified.

Comment: it probably isn't using that uv map. are you righting it the the uv map attribute that already exists (also do with a 2d vector)

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution that I have found, it is not perfect though.

Basically convert generated mesh into instance, so it is not used in hair curves generation:

[image]

But:

- Particles are generated on one side only
- Edge can't be merged, so seam is visible.

If you have found better solution to this problem, welcome to post